# How do i work in Visual Basic in VS Code or Mac?

Tags: windows, vb.net, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

sorry if the question is basic or does not have an answer but i have began my coding journey and due to classes i need to program basic code in "Visual Basic".

I have a Windows PC where i can code fine in Visual Studio 2022, but i have a MacBook Air as my laptop, i would like to code visual basic on it as well just small codes for my exams and class, i downloaded Visual Studio for Mac and it only allowed me to code in "C#" then i tried VS Code and selected VB on it, Python (With its extension) worked fine on VS Code, i can enter and run my code in the terminal but vb would always be a house of errors.

My question is, what is the appropriate way to program in visual basic on a mac (Latest macOS) (M1 Chip) and how can i get visual basic to work in VS Code?

Really appreciate anyone's time spent on answering this, have a good one!

Spent alot of hours downloading extensions that would help me run VB Code on VS Code, tried to get Visual Basic on Visual Studio for mac and that didnt help either.

The only thing that works right now is visual basic on visual studio 2022 on my windows pc. i want to code in vb on my mac. Python on vs code etc works fine not vb.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Basic is not officially supported on Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio for Mac. However, there are some third-party extensions that you can use to add support for Visual Basic on VS Code.

One such extension is "VBNET for Visual Studio Code" which can be found in the VS Code extension marketplace. This extension is a community-supported extension and may not be as stable as the official extensions.

Alternatively, you can use a Windows virtual machine on your Mac to run Visual Studio 2022 and use it to write and run Visual Basic code. This would allow you to use Visual Studio 2022 on your Mac, and you can work with Visual Basic code on your Mac.

It's worth noting that Visual Basic is not a popular language as it was in the past, many developers are not familiar with it and support for it is limited. If you have the opportunity, it might be worth your time to learn a more widely used and supported language like C# or Python.

where VS Code is a powerful, multi-language code editor that offers many features and customization options, making it a great choice for developers. It can be used for Visual Basic development and it's a good alternative for Visual Studio for Mac which does not support Visual Basic.

Comment: Hey there, really appreciate your response on this but that extension i cant find that extension VS Code, so the only way i have is either an online code runner or just using a VM on my mac (its an M1 Mac)